# Fetching the smallest and biggest values in firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebaserealime database for an android project using kotlin. when i try to fetch the smalest and biggist values from my database it doesn't get me anything more than 9.999 and nothing smaller than 0.1

used orederByValue and limiting it to first and last but nothing works, when trying to fetch last added value anit mpre or less than the bounde=ries i mentioned it works totally fine

```
databaseRef.orderByValue().addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val firstChild = snapshot.children.first()
        val minVal = firstChild?.value
        binding.minVoltage.text = minVal.toString()

        Log.d("maxMin", " getting min value: $minVal")

    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e("maxMin", "error getting min value")
    }
})

databaseRef.orderByValue().addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        val lastChild = snapshot.children.last()
        val maxVal = lastChild?.value
        binding.maxVoltage.text = maxVal.toString()

        Log.d("maxMin", " getting max value :$maxVal")

    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e("maxMin", "error getting max value")
    }
})
```

this is the JSON file as text

```
{
  "all": {
    "-NTEoauVV0hVWnRmEv3h": "1",
    "-NTEob96WZM838lMemE5": "2",
    "-NTEobPje-XGwkM7Pel0": "3",
    "-NTEobczRzkSY86Kj6pu": "4",
    "-NTEocBUXw5MKfAVRVUa": "6",
    "-NTEocPrKa6aVmghfU-L": "7",
    "-NTEocebJUkK_DSjugFK": "8",
    "-NTEocxMNdrtLbRPsQla": "9",
    "-NTEoeSy6AA-j5WZCHYR": "10",
    "-NTEooFyUtQAiu-noO_e": "0.1",
    "-NTEopQpWOIDrbk7EcgL": "0.5",
    "-NTEoq9qfm6zy2ffAbSU": "3",
    "-NTEoquLQNXUNxk0uvP4": "4.5",
    "-NTEorupU8SgQWCx-bkA": "6.1",
    "-NTEosnplfD0EVQgY59N": "2.3",
    "-NTEotvaQtpNSdfHbONq": "7.4",
    "-NTEoubCTwtPu0dN9v_d": "8.3",
    "-NTEov6hr3Ozxu45uF3C": "7.3",
    "-NTEovuxMtO_G8l6yB0U": "8.4",
    "-NTEowZCrPBUsrH3j-qv": "4.5",
    "-NTEoxNxbqGnz-QBF_Np": "8.2",
    "-NTEoy6pRWfmM0U7oKAL": "4",
    "-NTEozBJQbEPhESRxt_s": "2.9",
    "-NTEozu3PKBXh6y45Qj7": "8",
    "-NTEp-G3t4jFotsHmPgQ": "3",
    "-NTEp-TZBuUVUWG8XEce": "1",
    "-NTEp-goeGGSofX6vlF3": "2",
    "-NTEp023TWbQe3onDQj5": "6",
    "-NTEp1kBt1NiAoijzVnE": "6",
    "-NTFEpVIHTA8z_DUHhHL": "2",
    "-NTFFJc7lz-iY0azaFG_": "11",
    "-NTFJ-07b4zoVMuhzz7V": "-5",
    "-NTFPn8JM8-MuKyJcslB": "3",
    "-NTFPo8os6dQWBVYHw7g": "5",
    "-NTFPopdL8b_izl86Nm7": "7",
    "-NTFPq7GMsULeJyETC54": "9",
    "-NTFPrD5JxU8oeU4FQMu": "5",
    "-NTFPs9mkur4iNksqnR1": "0",
    "-NTFPucbvPps1bGs3VdT": "-5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the data at `databaseRef` in your database (as text please, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i've added the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the numbers as string values in the database, which means that Firebase applies [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) to them. In that order, the values show up like this:

```js
var json = {
  "-NTEoauVV0hVWnRmEv3h": "1",
  "-NTEob96WZM838lMemE5": "2",
  "-NTEobPje-XGwkM7Pel0": "3",
  "-NTEobczRzkSY86Kj6pu": "4",
  "-NTEocBUXw5MKfAVRVUa": "6",
  "-NTEocPrKa6aVmghfU-L": "7",
  "-NTEocebJUkK_DSjugFK": "8",
  "-NTEocxMNdrtLbRPsQla": "9",
  "-NTEoeSy6AA-j5WZCHYR": "10",
  "-NTEooFyUtQAiu-noO_e": "0.1",
  "-NTEopQpWOIDrbk7EcgL": "0.5",
  "-NTEoq9qfm6zy2ffAbSU": "3",
  "-NTEoquLQNXUNxk0uvP4": "4.5",
  "-NTEorupU8SgQWCx-bkA": "6.1",
  "-NTEosnplfD0EVQgY59N": "2.3",
  "-NTEotvaQtpNSdfHbONq": "7.4",
  "-NTEoubCTwtPu0dN9v_d": "8.3",
  "-NTEov6hr3Ozxu45uF3C": "7.3",
  "-NTEovuxMtO_G8l6yB0U": "8.4",
  "-NTEowZCrPBUsrH3j-qv": "4.5",
  "-NTEoxNxbqGnz-QBF_Np": "8.2",
  "-NTEoy6pRWfmM0U7oKAL": "4",
  "-NTEozBJQbEPhESRxt_s": "2.9",
  "-NTEozu3PKBXh6y45Qj7": "8",
  "-NTEp-G3t4jFotsHmPgQ": "3",
  "-NTEp-TZBuUVUWG8XEce": "1",
  "-NTEp-goeGGSofX6vlF3": "2",
  "-NTEp023TWbQe3onDQj5": "6",
  "-NTEp1kBt1NiAoijzVnE": "6",
  "-NTFEpVIHTA8z_DUHhHL": "2",
  "-NTFFJc7lz-iY0azaFG_": "11",
  "-NTFJ-07b4zoVMuhzz7V": "-5",
  "-NTFPn8JM8-MuKyJcslB": "3",
  "-NTFPo8os6dQWBVYHw7g": "5",
  "-NTFPopdL8b_izl86Nm7": "7",
  "-NTFPq7GMsULeJyETC54": "9",
  "-NTFPrD5JxU8oeU4FQMu": "5",
  "-NTFPs9mkur4iNksqnR1": "0",
  "-NTFPucbvPps1bGs3VdT": "-5"
};
var values = Object.values(json);
values.sort();
console.log(values);
```

As you can see, this is not the numerical sort order:

> "0.1",
> "0.5",
> "1",
> "1",
> "10",
> "11",
> "2",

The `"2"` shows after `"10"` and `"11"` here, because it's sorted alphabetically.

If you want to get proper numerical sorting, store the numerical values as actual numbers in the database - so that they show up without the `"` around them.